# All attempts to extract data from Twitter resulting in 'module' object has no attribute 'OAuthHandler'

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth, pip, tweepy

I tried to extract data from Twitter and I followed all steps that should be done but I do not know what is wrong!

```
import csv
#from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler
import tweepy

Access_token = "........"
Access_token_secret = "..........."
consumer_key = "..............."
consumer_secret = "........."

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(Access_token, Access_token_secret)
auth.set_access_token(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

But there is hidden issue!

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dddd/PycharmProjects/Project1/tweepy.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tweepy
  File "C:\Users\dddd\PycharmProjects\Project1\tweepy.py", line 10, in <module>
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(Access_token, Access_token_secret)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OAuthHandler'
```

Comment: the above code is part of my codes

Comment: Does your commented-out import statement imply that OAuthHandler is actually in the tweepy.auth submodule?

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler
authorize = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
authorize.set_access_token(Access_token, Access_token_secret)
```